# In Java source code, why ArrayList.add has parameter as generic type T while addAll has parameter as generic type <? extends E>?

Tags: java, generics

Here's the source code of Java `ArrayList` (using java 1.8)

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

---

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

I am not very clear why we can only use `E` for `add()` while we can use `<? extends E>` for `addAll()`

Comment: So are you asking why there isn't a syntax that looks like `add(? extends E e)`? If that is what you are asking, how would that mean anything different from `add(E e)`?

Comment: Because, assuming `F` extends `E`, `F` is an `E`, but a `Collection<F>` is NOT a `Collection<E>`, so you have to specify that you accept a `Collection<F>` where `F` extends `E`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because if you have an `ArrayList<Number>` you can `add` a `Integer` to it and a `Number` and a `Double` because they are all sub types of `E`/`Number` but you could not `addAll` a `ArrayList<Integer>` if the signature were `addAll(Collection<E> c)` because an `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a (subtype of) `ArrayList<Number>` because in Java generics are *invariant*. Only if you define it as `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` can you add lists with more specific generic subtypes. That basically means *"any collection with a generic parameter that is a subtype of `E`"*

Comment: Very good explanation, emphasis on `because [Java] generics are invariant`

Comment: Thanks. but why method add(E) support all sub types of E? is that covariant?

Comment: @LeonloveKaren I was sort-of expecting that question and I did not understand the difference either when I first heard about it. The difference is that `ArrayList<Integer>` is still generic even though the generic parameter is known and fixed and at that point the two generics `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<E>` do not work together. But `Integer` on the other hand is itself not generic, it is just a regular type. And it therefore *can* work with `E`.